# Scrapy multiple regular expressions in LinkExtractor seem to be not working

Tags: json, regex, scrapy, web-crawler

I've got my regular expressions inside a JSON file. This file gets loaded as a configuration for my spider. The spider creates one LinkExtractor with `allow` and `deny` regular expression rules.
I'd like to:

- crawl and scrape product pages (scraping / parsing is NOT working)
- crawl category pages
- avoid general pages (about us, privacy, etc.)

It all works well on some shops, but not on others and I believe it's a problem of my Regular Expressions.

```
"rules": [
    {
        "deny": ["\\/(customer\\+service|ways\\+to\\+save|sponsorship|order|cart|company|specials|checkout|integration|blog|brand|account|sitemap|prefn1=)\\/"],
        "follow": false
    },
    {
        "allow": ["com\\/store\\/details\\/"],
        "follow": true,
        "use_content": true
    },
    {
        "allow": ["com\\/store\\/browse\\/"],
        "follow": true
    }
],
```

URL patterns:

> **Products:**
>   https://www.example.com/store/details/Nike+SB-Portmore-II-Solar-Canvas-Mens
>   https://www.example.com/store/details/Coleman+Renegade-Mens-Hiking
>   https://www.example.com/store/details/Mueller+ATF3-Ankle-Brace
>   https://www.example.com/store/details/Planet%20Fitness+18
>   https://www.example.com/store/details/Lifeline+Pro-Grip-Ring
>   https://www.example.com/store/details/Nike+Phantom-Vision
>
> **Categories:**
>   https://www.example.com/store/browse/footwear/
>   https://www.example.com/store/browse/apparel/
>   https://www.example.com/store/browse/fitness/
>
> **Deny:**
>   https://www.example.com/store/customer+service/Online+Customer+Service
>   https://www.example.com/store/checkout/
>   https://www.example.com/store/ways+to+save/
>   https://www.example.com/store/specials
>   https://www.example.com/store/company/Privacy+Policy
>   https://www.example.com/store/company/Terms+of+Service

Loading the rules from JSON inside my spider `__init__`

```
for rule in self.MY_SETTINGS["rules"]:
    allow_r = ()
    if "allow" in rule.keys():
        allow_r = [a for a in rule["allow"]]

    deny_r = ()
    if "deny" in rule.keys():
        deny_r = [d for d in rule["deny"]]

    restrict_xpaths_r = ()
    if "restrict_xpaths" in rule.keys():
        restrict_xpaths_r = [rx for rx in rule["restrict_xpaths"]]

    Sportygenspider.rules.append(Rule(
        LinkExtractor(
            allow=allow_r,
            deny=deny_r,
            restrict_xpaths=restrict_xpaths_r,
        ),
        follow=rule["follow"],
        callback='parse_item' if ("use_content" in rule.keys()) else None
    ))
```

If I do a `pprint(vars(onerule.link_extractor))` I can see the Python regex correctly:

```
'deny_res': [re.compile('\\/(customer\\+service|sponsorship|order|cart|company|specials|checkout|integration|blog|account|sitemap|prefn1=)\\/')]

{'allow_domains': set(),
 'allow_res': [re.compile('com\\/store\\/details\\/')],

{'allow_domains': set(),
 'allow_res': [re.compile('com\\/store\\/browse\\/')],
```

Testing the regex in https://regex101.com/ seems to be fine as well (despite: I'm using `\\/` in my JSON file and `\/` in regex101.com)

In my spider logfile, I can see that the produce pages are being crawled, but not parsed:

```
2019-02-01 08:25:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/store/details/FILA+Hometown-Mens-Lifestyle-Shoes/5345120230028/_/A-6323521;> (referer: https://www.example.com/store/browse/footwear)  
2019-02-01 08:25:47 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/store/details/FILA+D-Formation-Mens-Lifestyle-Shoes/5345120230027/_/A-6323323> (ref
```

Why does the spider not parse the product pages?
(same code, different JSON works on different shops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging and testing, I figured that I had to change the order of the rules.

1. Products to scrape rule
2. Deny about us etc.
3. Categories to follow

Now it is working.

```
"rules": [
    {
        "allow": ["com\\/store\\/details\\/"],
        "follow": true,
        "use_content": true
    },
    {
        "deny": ["\\/(customer\\+service|ways\\+to\\+save|sponsorship|order|cart|company|specials|checkout|integration|blog|brand|account|sitemap|prefn1=)\\/"],
        "follow": false
    },
    {
        "allow": ["com\\/store\\/browse\\/"],
        "follow": true
    }
],
```